# Why does JavaFX 2 create more TableRows than required?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2

In JavaFX 2's `TableView`, there is an API to add a `RowFactory`. That factory is used to create the `TableRow`s; it is use for cases where the developer wants features (like a tooltip) to span the entire row.

Now, working with the feature, I noticed that the `RowFactory` is called not called once per visible row, but instead once more.

If you execute [this piece of code](https://gist.github.com/2895713), you'll notice that the UI shows 16 rows in the UI, but the counter on the console counts a 17th line.
What's curious is that the extraneous line appears to be at the beginning and filled with data, not maybe an invisible extra line at the end.
I'd think it to be the header, but in the [JavaFX code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.1/master/rt), it does not look like that's the case.

Can you explain this observation?

Comment: This is a fairly deep implementation detail, you may want to post your question to the [JavaFX development mailing list](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/), which is monitored by the JavaFX developers.